# Can you have multiple versions of a gem in a Gemfile?

Tags: ruby, rubygems, bundler

What I would like would be something like this:

```
gem 'rack', '1.3.3', '1.2.4'
```

So that when gems require different versions of rack, they are all appeased.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can set an intervall of allowed gems

```
gem 'rack', '<1.3.3', '>1.2.4'
```

It will load the most actual one inside the selected intervall.

But I don't think you can require different gem versions.
If a gem would be loaded in different versions, each class and module must get it own namespace to avoid to overwrite the methods of the gem.

Comment: There's a lot of cases where new versions of Gems do a complete refactor and change their namespace/module names as well. The Mongo 1.x series went from `MongoClient` namespace to `Mongo::Client` and would have been a perfect use case for supporting multiple versions of the same gem.

Comment: @knut What do you mean by most actual one?

Comment: @Kamesh The gem with the highest version number.

Answer (score 14):

No, you are not able to have multiple gem versions loaded at the same time. This is because, as knut highlighted, the code would conflict. How would a gem know to use the `1.2.4` version of Rack as opposed to the `1.3.3` version of Rack? It can't.

Also: with Bundler, all gem dependencies *must* be satisfied in order for the bundling process to complete. If you have a gem that *explicitly requires* Rack 1.2.4 (i.e `= 1.2.4` is in the `gemspec` for that gem) and then another gem that requires a version of Rack such as `>= 1.3` then these gem versions will conflict and Bundler will tell you so.

Comment: Great answer! Did the last sentence get truncated? ("then these gem versions...") Any chance of adding the rest? I'm keen to read to the end :-)

Comment: @tjmw: It's not that exciting... it's just "will conflict and Bundler will tell you so."

Comment: This seems pretty lame--can't one alias each different version into a unique namespace? Does that require one to publish the gems oneself currently?

Answer (score 3):

I came upon this question because I wanted to blacklist certain broken upstream gem versions which were buggy.  While you can't do

`gem 'rack', '1.3.3', '1.2.4'`

you *can* have multiple `!=` constraints to rule out versions that you know to be problematic:

`gem 'rack', '!= 1.3.0.beta2', '!= 1.3.0.beta'`