# Bundler - cannot load 2 different versions of the exact same gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bundler

I've watched this presentation on [how Bundler works](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4DqzaqeeMgY) and one of the reasons Bundler was invented was to solve 'activation errors', for eg:

```
LoadError: can't activate rack (~> 1.0.0, runtime) for ['actonpack-2.3.5'], already activated rack-1.1.0 for ['thin-1.2.7']
```

Does this basically means that you cannot run 2 different versions of the exact same gem at a same time, in a single Ruby process?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot have two different versions of the same gem loaded the same program, because they could conflict and override each other's methods. For example, suppose you have a gem which contains the following:

```
# In gem version 1.0
class AneMaria
  def self.name
    "Ane"
  end
end

######

# In gem version 2.0
class AneMaria
  def self.name
    "Maria"
  end
end
```

And then in your code, if you call `AneMaria.name`, what should it return??

One of the reasons tools like `bundler` were created was to *prevent* this from happening accidentally -- so no, you cannot specify 2 different versions of a gem to load simultaneously. (Also, I don't think you'll ever want to do that!)

See also [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7476243/1954610), which explains things a little more.